# Click on DIV to show image path in an alternate DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div placed outside the image div

```
<div id="" class="TextShow">Click</div>

<div style="">
<img src="images/file.jpg" id="2">
</div>
```

javascript/jquery code below to get the image path.

```
$('.TextShow').click(function() {
var ImageShowed = $('#2').attr('src');
alert(ImageShowed);
});
```

When I click on .TextShow the ImageShowed is NULL.

My question is, why am I not getting the image path.

Comment: As per you edit, this should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `{` and have added an extra `[` which as nothing to do here.

Here's your corrected code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.TextShow').click(function () { // << this was missing
        var ImageShowed = $('#2').attr('src'); // << removed the extra [
        alert(ImageShowed);
    });
});
```

Also, think of wrapping your code inside `jQuery(function($) { ... });` to be sure your jQuery code is executed after the DOM is loaded.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hnkp40g/)

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax problems:

1. first line missing '{' at the end
2. Second line contains extra '[' that should be removed

your code should look like this:

```
$('.TextShow').click(function() {
var ImageShowed = $('#2').attr('src'); 
alert(ImageShowed);
});
```

here is a working sample: http://jsbin.com/wejozopeci/1/edit?html,js,output